# Why php code is not validation

Tags: php

Here my if condition is showing "new" as output why? I expect "old":

```
$d = date("Y"); 
$string = substr($v, 0,  4) . '<br>';  //here string stores 2015

if($string != $d) {
    echo "new";         
} else {
    echo 'old';         
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($string);` ?

Comment: I doubt that `var_dump($string);` **only** shows you `2015`. So what is the real output? (From a-z, most times it's something like: `string(4) "2015"` or so)

Answer (score 3):

Why would `2015` be the same as `2015<br>` ?

As noted by Gordon, you're comparing two strings, so it's really like this

```
if ( "2015" == "2015<br>" ) // false
```

Stop adding the `<br>` and it probably works

```
$d = date("Y"); 
$string = substr($v, 0,  4);

if($string != $d) {
    echo "new";         
} else {
    echo 'old';         
}
```

Comment: @adeneo You may want to give the `AH!!!` effect to OP by letting him writing: `var_dump($string);` and then let him look at the output, so he sees it with his own eyes :)

Comment: @Rizier123 - but `var_dump` in a HTLM document will parse the break as HTML, but even if you can't see it, doesn't mean it's not present in the string

Comment: @adeneo Well he won't see the break line directly unless he looks at the source code, but he still can see it: `var_dump("2015<br>");` -> `string(8) "2015
"` I think then he should see that 8 can't match with only 2015

Comment: @Rizier123 - Yes, that's what I was thinking, and as Gordon is saying, that would be true as both are strings, I was just stumped at how PHP does type conversion.

Comment: Yes, @adeneo you are right.Code considered  <br> too. Thank you for valuable suggestion.